# How to add local maven repository (m2repository) to AIDE?

Tags: android, android-ide, aide

I have AIDE app installed on my smartphone with "m2repository" downloaded and i want to use it in other device without downloading it again.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was in front of my eyes.just copy m2repository full path using "es file explorer " or any one similar then open aide-ide and tape the three dots on the right of AppBar then tape more.. then settings then build and run then local maven repositories and finally past the path that you copied earlier and voila .